# Servlet caching resources

Tags: java, performance, servlets

We want to cache resources in a servlet what we can use from below?

- `@PostConstruct`
- `@PreDestroy`
- `init()`
- `service()`
- `destroy()`

Anything else?

Comment: Thinking about why the methods are called that way would be a good start...

Comment: I believe these are JavaEE 5 annotations. see the link for you info:http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html

Comment: i'm confused between PostConstruct & init() and PreDestroy & destroy(). One is called right at the beginning/end and the other one when everything regarding a class is available and set to do some operation.

Comment: any idea what should be used?

Comment: You generally use `init` and `destroy` and only use `@PostConstruct` and `@PreDestroy` if for whatever reason you can't get get by using only the former. This is rare though.